# How to understand "If you don't do shit, you can't boo shit."

Tags: meaning, quotes

"If you don't do shit, you can't boo shit." - Will.I.Am, Musician

Comment: Poetics, musicians, postmodernists, and wall-sitting anthropomorphic eggs can make words mean just whatever they like them to mean. Barring Will.I.Am, the only answer *anyone* could offer you, here or anywhere else, would be unadulterated personal opinion. Since StackExchange in general prefers *objective* answers, we cannot respond to this question, and are obliged to close it.

Comment: "boo" means to cry if that helps.

Comment: At the risk of kindling Dan Bron's righteous wrath (righteous because his comment is, in fact, exactly right), I will venture to say that the quoted language strikes me as being a variant of a much older expression: "If you didn't vote, you can't complain"—an absurdity on its face, but nevertheless a statement intended to chastise people who don't like the status quo but don't participate in efforts to change it through approved channels. I suppose that in Will.I.Am's formulation, the channels don't even have to be approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I've never heard this (it's not a well-established idiom), I would take it to mean,

> If you don't *do* anything, then don't complain about the quality of what other people are doing, because at least they're trying to *do something*.

It slightly depends on the meaning of the second "shit". Shit can mean a lot of things. It can mean something of low quality, it can mean anything at all.

He didn't do *shit* about it = he didn't do anything at all about it.
That's some good *shit*. (No need to translate, I hope.)
Don't give me any of that *shit* = don't make bad arguments (or other)

As an extreme example, if all you do is sit around and complain, then don't criticize anyone who is at least trying - but not succeeding - to *do*.

If you're a musician, you're trying to create something, whereas people who aren't musicians shouldn't criticize. This, of course, assumes that *those who can, do; and those who can't, criticize.*

I'm not a writer, but I'll criticize Dan Brown if he comes up in conversation(thankfully, this is a rare event), I dislike his writing that much. And I agree [with his critics](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/10049454/Dont-make-fun-of-renowned-Dan-Brown.html), even if they don't write books.

Comment: It's always good to see someone take a gratuitous swipe at Dan Brown.

Answer (score 3):

[Theodore Roosevelt](http://www.theodore-roosevelt.com/trsorbonnespeech.html) said the same thing, albeit more eloquently:

**THE MAN IN THE ARENA**

> It is not the critic who counts; not the man who points out how the
>   strong man stumbles, or where the doer of deeds could have done them
>   better. The credit belongs to the man who is actually in the arena,
>   whose face is marred by dust and sweat and blood; who strives
>   valiantly; who errs, who comes short again and again, because there is
>   no effort without error and shortcoming; but who does actually strive
>   to do the deeds; who knows great enthusiasms, the great devotions; who
>   spends himself in a worthy cause; who at the best knows in the end the
>   triumph of high achievement, and who at the worst, if he fails, at
>   least fails while daring greatly, so that his place shall never be
>   with those cold and timid souls who neither know victory nor
>   defeat.
>  <sub>[Theodore Roosevelt:Excerpt from the speech
>   "Citizenship In A Republic" delivered at the Sorbonne, in Paris,
>   France on 23 April, 1910](http://www.theodore-roosevelt.com/trsorbonnespeech.html)</sub>

Critics of a performance might "*boo*" the performer. As a musician, *Will.I.Am* probably has endured his fair share of *boos*

> **boo**
>
> Said to show disapproval or contempt, especially at a performance or
>   athletic contest.
>
> An utterance of “boo” to show disapproval or contempt:
>   *the audience greeted this comment with boos and hisses*
>  <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/boo)</sub>

In this case, "*boo shit*" refers to the disapproval or contempt the critics might have of the inevitable shortcomings and failures of those who dare greatly.

The meaning is related to the concept of *empathy*

> **Developing Empathy: Walk a mile in someone’s shoes**
>   *By Steve Mueller*
>
> … before you criticize this person. The following article has a lot to
>   share about compassion, empathy and in general the ability to think
>   yourself into another person’s shoes, if you so want. It will also
>   show you what you can do to develop and cultivate empathy. The origin
>   of the famous proverb *“before you criticize a man, walk a mile in his
>   shoes”* was quite difficult to find, as there are many who simply
>   rephrased and added their own “spin” to this commonly known quote.
>   Many of those modern quotations added the sentence *“… That way, you
>   are a mile away from them and have their shoes”*, which naturally adds
>   a funny spin to the quote, but it (unfortunately) has nothing in
>   common with the original thoughts behind the fantastic proverb.
>
> The earliest traces of the enlightening part of the proverb date back
>   to the Cherokee tribe of Native Americans, who said *"Don’t judge a man
>   until you have walked a mile in his shoes,"* Nelle Harper Lee, an
>   American authoress, was seemingly inspired by the saying of the
>   Amerindians in her book “*To Kill a Mockingbird*”, where she wrote
>
> *“You never really know a man until you understand things from his
>   point of view, until you climb into his skin and walk around in it.”*
>
> <sub>Lee, Harper. To Kill a Mockingbird. J.B. Lippincott & Co., 1960</sub>
>
> and thereby brought the saying to a wider public and increased its
>   popularity distinctly.
>   <sub>[planetofsuccess.com](http://www.planetofsuccess.com/blog/2011/developing-empathy-walk-a-mile-in-someone%E2%80%99s-shoes/)</sub>

Comment: That is eloquent. How, then, do you translate the second "shit"?

Comment: I interpret the 2nd "shit" as the inevitable shortcomings and failures of those who dare greatly"

Comment: Fair enough. +1